# How to calculate largest array dimensions in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, out-of-memory

I have run into problem creating NxN zeros array in matlab where N ~ 1e6.
So I want to figure out what limit do I have on N.
I am also using linux so `memory` command does not work for me.

I have 16Gb RAM and 39Gb SWAP space.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memory.html#brl1pdy

Comment: @Cheery, like I said above, memory command does not work on linux

Comment: But the link gives idea how to estimate memory usage )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91711-what-is-the-maximum-matrix-size-for-each-platform) seems to answer your question. For Linux 32 bits the maximum number of elements is ~312e6, while for Linux 64 bit it's ~300e6. In any case, you should be able to confirm this by directly trying to allocate matrices around those sizes and see if they work or not.